# Expo App failing when run standalone (Can’t update build)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, asyncstorage

I’m trying to run an app that works fine on the expo go environment but not working when built and installed in a device. I tried deleting and rebuilding but the same errors keep popping up even if I fix certain errors.

Now the app runs but gets stuck after the splash screen.

**Issues**:

There was issue due to Async storage as it has been depreciated but the important thing to note is, I didn't use Async storage in my code. It is being called by another node module (Firebase Auth) which I use for configuring signup and login.
Im unable to reflect the changes the build after making the change in local machine even if I delete and rebuild some issues that I fixed (for example a small misspelled word - fontesLoaded) in the local machine still shows as an error.
There is 2 syntax error (missing , ) (missing undefined) in 2 places in the file where there is no comma.

Versions used:

"@babel/core": "^7.22.10"
"@babel/traverse": "7.16.7"
"react-native": "0.72.3",
"firebase": "^10.2.0",
"expo": "~49.0.7",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
Github link: https://github.com/Raghul-Ragavan/JournalApp

I tried rebuilding the app by deleting the old build . Tried EAS update.